# Trigger GitHub action manually and on schedule

Tags: yaml, workflow, github-actions

I want to trigger GitHub action manually and on schedule but the following code produces and error

```yaml
name: Update data

on: 
   workflow_dispatch
   schedule:
     - cron: "0 5 */30 * *"
```

I'm searching for the solution how to do it correctly and have both options.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you need a colon after workflow_dispatch.

```
name: Update data

on: 
   workflow_dispatch:
   schedule:
     - cron: "0 5 */30 * *"
```

Comment: the problem with this is that it does not use the inputs, if you set some in the `workflow_dispatch`